# PhoneGap iOS keyboard accessory bar not hiding in app

Tags: cordova

I am working on an iOS PhoneGap v2.9 app that does load some pages that are hosted on a remote web site.  The cordova plugins work in the remote pages, but the settings in the config.xml are not being passed.  For example, setting the hideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar to true hides the bar in the native html files, but not on the remotely hosted pages.  Does anyone know if this is by design?

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade the cordova version with 3.3.0.

For accessory bar Please review this thread:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3020?focusedCommentId=13784637&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13784637

I linked you to the comment to start reading from. The user Shazron Abdullah are the answers you need to pay attention to.

Regards